# Is it possible to specify absolute path in Docker-compose for build context?

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, yaml

Here is the scenario:

1. SQL SERVER related files at: C:\Temp\docker
2. .NET API related files at: C:\Users\Samurai\source\repos\ApiForDocker\ApiForDocker

As I understand from this official sample docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  web:
    build: .  // relative path goes over here
    links:
      - "db:database"
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Now I could keep my docker-compose file in either of the folder. 1) or 2) 
but how do I provide correct path for other without having to move files? 
The reason I don't want to move files now is because I am afraid that it may result in rebuilding of container without cache. Though that may not be a big deal for me now but I am just trying to learn.

EDIT:

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: C:\Temp\docker
            environment: 
                ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
                SA_PASSWORD="Pwd12345!"
        ports:
            - "11433:1433"
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.sqlserver.build contains unsupported option: 'environment'
```

Comment: The documentation for the `context:` directory suggests it's not required to be a relative path, so you could use the absolute path to both image trees.  Similarly if you're using a bind mount to store the database data on the host it can use an absolute path.  Is there a specific problem you run into if you try it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried absolute path (see my edit) it is giving me `ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.sqlserver.build contains unsupported option: 'environment'` not sure if its because of absolute path

Comment: In the updated file, `environment:` is indented one step too many; it needs to not be under `build:`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to files outside the docker build context. So, you either have to set the build context to the first common directory containing all you want, or copy the files that will do into the image under a directory and build your image there.

As long as the file contents are the same, docker will be able to use the build cache.

Comment: Here is the thing. I have a database restore script in one of the files. `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Temp\docker\AdventureWorksLT2017.bak'` Now as you can see if I move this file I will have to change the path of .bak file.  I am not sure what is going to happen.

Comment: Is that file used at build time, or at runtime? If it is at runtime, then you need to put the file to that directory in the container, but it can live anywhere on the filesystem at build time as long as that location is under the build context.